# Setting up shared common Pods for multiple targets within projects

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install Pod using  `abstract_target` to share common Pods for multiple target. I am follow [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#abstract_target) to install Pods. But it generates following error.

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `abstract_target' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fcd7380d098>. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

 #  from /Users/Sagar/Desktop/CocoaPodsMultipleTarget/Podfile:5
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  abstract_target "Networking" do
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I updated my CocoaPods and my current version is :

```
/Users/Sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

Below is my Podfile.

```
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!


abstract_target 'Networking' do

    pod 'AlamoFire'


    target 'CocoaPodsMultipleTarget' do

    platform :ios, '9.0'

        pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

    end


    target 'MyWatchDemo Extension' do

    platform :watchos, '2.0'

    end

end
```

Is there any thing wrong with my Podfile ?

Any help or suggestion should be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem; turned out rvm was loading an old version of cocoapods. Imploded rvm and reinstalled, the installed the latest cocoapods 1.0 beta... and it worked! You can check what version is actually being used by `$ which pod` and `$ pod --version`

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, i already installed `cocoapods-1.0.0.beta.2` ,but not working. If you have solution then please post answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your version of CocoaPods is 1.0 and not 0.39.0? Using `abstract_target` only works on 1.0 and above. In your terminal...

Check version:

```
$ pod --version
```

Update for the pre-release version:

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

For reference: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html